# Designing JS with Const

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. Is there any better way to use the scroll option once and use it for all other functions. I am not sure how can I redesign it as const.

```
module.exports.xyz = function (browser, done) {
   browser
  .execute('window.scroll(0,2000)')
  .clickWaitForElementByCssWithCatch(css, isDisplayed, 30000, 1000)
  .nodeify(done);
};

module.exports.abc = function (browser, done) {
   browser
  .execute('window.scroll(0,2000)')
  .clickWaitForElementByCssWithCatch(css, isDisplayed, 30000, 1000)
  .nodeify(done);
};

module.exports.efg = function (browser, done) {
   browser
  .execute('window.scroll(0,2000)')
  .clickWaitForElementByCssWithCatch(css, isDisplayed, 30000, 1000)
  .nodeify(done);
};
```

Comment: "I am getting sonar complain for scroll window", what do you mean? If there is an error share it.

Comment: It means I cant merge my code with sonar problem. I have to fix it.

Comment: I get that bud, what is the error you are getting. Not in your own words, copy and paste the error into your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The String ('window.scroll(0,2000)') is repeated 3 times and that is the complaint you get from Sonar.

You should define a variable at the top of your file:

```
var js_code = 'window.scroll(0,2000)';
```

And then use this as a parameter: `browser.execute(js_code)`

Comment: Perfectly, worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @adnanabdal I thought so. Although your question is indeed not really clear, it is perfectly clear for somebody who did code reviews in Sonar. For the future try to state the issue more clear. Can you please also up vote the answer so that others don't get the wrong idea? Thanks and good luck.

Comment: Sure, I will. Thanks for your prompt help.